# Missing folders in eclipse (Android Development)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have re installed android sdk (`platform 2.3.3`). Now I have different set of folders on my `package explorer`.

For example there are folders called `drawable-xhdpi` , `Android dependencies` which weren't there before. Also by default the main.xml is now generating on `RelativeLayout` instead `LinearLayout`. 
How to avoid that?

`Layout-land` folder is missing as well.

How can I get the previous folder set?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Each folder has its purpose. If you miss one, you can create it manually. Otherwise, if you don't need a folder, you can delete it.

Comment: can I get Landscape mode by using manually created Layout-land?

Comment: Sure you can. No matter if it's created automatically or manually.

Comment: you don't need to avoid them, just follow the android purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were using an older version of android SDK. When you reinstalled the SDK it got updated. Folders like `drawable-xhdpi` are automatically added to the package explorer in the newer version of Android SDK.
To avoid this, degrade your SDK version or delete unwanted folders manually. You can find the older releases from this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html).